# String file path does not work when used as command argument

Tags: bash, unix, cat

I'm trying to use a relative path as a argument to another command. Seems that the auto-expansion of the path doesn't work because it's a string. How can you pass a string variable to the `cat` command so that it resolves the file?

```
PEM="~/.ssh/my.pem"; cat $PEM
// cat: ~/.ssh/my.pem: No such file or directory

PEM=~/.ssh/my.pem; cat $PEM
// gives key
```

Answer (score 4):

Tilde (`~`) expansion is not done by the shell when put inside quotes or is escaped.

The expansion correctly happens when you put `~` outside quotes:

```
PEM=~"/.ssh/my.pem"; cat "$PEM"
```

Instead you can also leverage the `HOME` environment variable:

```
PEM="$HOME/.ssh/my.pem"; cat "$PEM"
```